# How to make STS to recompile the project when React JS code is changed in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: reactjs, spring, eclipse, autocomplete, spring-tool-suite

I am working on a project, where **front-end** and **back-end** are ***Tightly coupled***. We are using React JS for frontend, and Java & Spring for backend. Since these are tightly coupled, we had to compile in VS Code, and Refresh in STS to reflect the UI code we've changed in VS Code. This is eating a lot of time.

I'm looking to find a way to **avoid the manual refresh** step in STS and **it should be done automatically**, since STS is taking toomuch time for Refreshing & Building Workspace.

Someone please guide me.

Thank You.

Comment: can you provide a sample project and sample setup to play with to see what exactly is going on and how to avoid that?

Comment: another thought: did you try to work on the Spring backend application in VS Code as well? There is quite good Java and Spring extensions available for VS Code. Just curious to hear from you what the challenges are and what would be necessary to provide a smooth VS Code only dev experience here.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise on what you mean by a 'manual refresh'? Do you mean you need to run an Eclipse project 'build' or do you just need Eclipse to become aware of files that have changed on the file system? If the latter there is an option in Eclipse to automaticall refresh workspace using 'native hooks or polling' but since I'm not actuall sure what you want, I'm not sure this is what you need or not.